# How to run data driven tests parallelly in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, parallel-testing, robotframework-browser

I have N number of test cases in my csv file and i have added it as a test template as shown below

```
Test Template    My test template


*** Test Cases ***
sample testcase    ${field1}    ${field2}       test1      test2

*** Keywords ***
My test template
    [Arguments]     ${field1}    ${field2}
    /* some code here */
```

Let say i have a csv file like the below which has more than 100 records

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCy9F.png)

Now if i have to run all these in parallel, can anyone explain how to do that?

Tried pabot -testlevelsplit and  pabot --processes N [path to tests] but this runs only one test and does not support when we have case like the above for data driven testing

I am expecting to run all tests in parallel for data driven testing scenarios

Comment: Hello @pradeep, maybe removing the texts 'test1' and 'test2' from `*** Test Cases ***` will help? Also, these pages have some information: https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver?tab=readme-ov-file#pabot-and-datadriver and https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver/issues/70 that might help. Also, please share the error messages that you received. Will be easy to find a solution.

Comment: Not facing any error kind of thing. But when the input is given in the form of a csv file, cannot use pabot to run tests parallelly. The tests are only executed sequentially

Comment: datadriver **needs** `--pabotlib` also to be passed or it wont work correctly. Another approach would be to preprocess your csv into chunks and just run robot with those chunks and combine the outputs afterwards.